# Get data from one table and for each record from this table insert data into another table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have 1 tables userinfo as shown below.There may be 1000 records.
I want to get each record from table userinfo and insert into tblRating.
For RatingQue1,RatingQue2,RatingQue3 i want add '4'.I want final result of tblRating as shown in tblRating below.

userinfo

```
 Id   empname managername     
  1    E1      M1
  2    E2      M1
  .     .       .
  .     .       .
  100   E100    M1
```

tblRating

```
 Id  ratingby   ratedto  RatingQue1 RatingQue2 RatingQue3 Avg 
 1     M1        E1        4            4          4       4
 2     M1        E2        4            4          4       4     
 .     .          .        .             .         .       .
 .     .          .        .             .         .       .
 100   M1        E100      4            4          4       4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
DECLARE c CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT Ename
FROM Tegra

DECLARE @id nvarchar(50)

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Rating2
SELECT 'Manager','E1', @id, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4       

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id
END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use Cursors in your query it will slow down your query performance

use following it gives o/p as you want:

create this two table (rating,userinfo ) before executing this query

```
**Insert into rating
select *,4,4,4,4 from userinfo**
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help

Tables

```
create table userinfo(id int,emp varchar(20),manager varchar(20));
create table rating (id int,ratedby varchar(20),ratedto varchar(20),r1 int,r2 int
                 ,r3 int,avg int);
```

Some test data

```
insert into userinfo values(1,'E1','M1');
insert into userinfo values(2,'E2','M2');
insert into userinfo values(4,'E4','M4');
insert into userinfo values(3,'E3','M3');
```

Required queries

```
insert into rating (id,ratedby,ratedto) (select id,manager,emp from userinfo);
update rating set r1=4,r2=4,r3=4;
```

You can update the `avg` column with another query. Also i used `int` for testing, you can use suitable `data types` [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68278/1/0)